# Coefficents of these partition-based polyomials are $0, \pm1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, partitions

This is a follow up on [my earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353715/an-identity-for-polynomials-over-partitions).

Given an integer partition $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_{\ell(\lambda)})$ of $n$ where $\ell(\lambda)$ is the length of $\lambda$, associate $\tilde\lambda'=\lambda,0$ found by appending one extra zero at the right end of $\lambda$. Further, define the following numerics $a(\lambda)_j=\tilde\lambda_j-\tilde\lambda_{j+1}$ for $j=1,2,\dots,\ell(\lambda)$.

For example, if $\lambda=(3,2,1,1)$ and $\tilde\lambda=(3,2,1,1,0)$ and $a(\lambda)=(1,1,0,1)$.

> **QUESTION.** Is it true that the coefficients of the polynomial $A_n(q)$ are all in $\{-1,0,1,2\}$? 
>   $$A_n(q):=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}q^{n-\lambda_1}
> \prod_{a(\lambda)_j\geq1}\frac{(q^{2a(\lambda)_j}-1)(q-1)}{q+1}.$$

**REMARK.** In fact, it appears that only coefficient of the middle-term can possibly be equal to $2$.

Comment: Since you're summing over all partitions, any reason why we need to take the conjugates first? The only reference to $\lambda$ itself seems to be the exponent of $q$ in the outer sum, and that can be replaced by $\lambda'_1$, right?

Comment: @user44191: edited accordingly.